# Nokogiri communication with Microsoft WCF (Binary)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wcf, nokogiri

I am using Ruby (Nokogiri) to talk to a service written in Microsoft WCF.  Recently developers have changed this to use a binary representation instead of plain text. Does Nokogiri support this?

Comment: Is the binary just compressed XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Nokogiri will not read binary data.

I've found [bindata](http://bindata.rubyforge.org/) very useful to read binary data.

Good luck!